# Система кэширования в битрикс

Tags: битрикс, отладка, кэширование

Есть ли в битрикс кэш помимо папок `bitrix/cache` и `bitrix/managed_cache`?
После редактирования шаблона я удаляю содержимое этих директорий, но результат вывода страницы меняется только через некоторое время.

Comment: Больше похоже на кеш бразуреа или веб-сервера, но не битрикс.

Comment: Нет это не кэш браузера, точно. Это что-то в самом битриксе, я не в первый раз такое встречаю в битриксе. Возможно кэш апача какой-то. Eсть варианты, как можно проверить это?

Comment: А кнопкой "Сбросить кэш" вы почему не пользуетесь?

Answer (score 0):

**Не удаляйте** папки с кешем вручную - можете потом словить проблемы с кешем.
Удаляйте либо кнопкой на панели (под админом), либо в админке по пути
*Настройки => Настройки продукта => Автокеширование*